# Center the text and bullet of an <li> element

Tags: html, css

I'm brushing up on my CSS skills by going through these challenges, and I'm having trouble with the very first one (see image below).
strong text

[image: CSS Challenge 1]

I can center the text, but the bullets aren't getting centered with it. See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shbfsoq6/)

```css
li {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List Number 1</li>
  <li>List Number 2</li>
  <li>List Number 3</li>
  <li>List Number 4</li>
  <li>List Number 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I’m not sure what you want to do. Do you want it to look like in the image? Then you’re already done. If you increase the text length randomly in that fiddle, you can see that it behaves like that.

Comment: @poke it's actually not by default on Chrome - https://jsfiddle.net/shbfsoq6/3/

Comment: Oh well, that’s funny. It looks exactly as desired in Firefox only. That explains my confusion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way might be setting list style position to inside.

```css
li {
  list-style-position: inside;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List Number 1</li>
  <li>List  2</li>
  <li>List Number 3</li>
  <li>List 4</li>
  <li>List Number 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly, and was the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your css its work.

```
li {
  text-align:center;
  list-style-type:none;
}
li:before{
  content:'\2022';
    margin-right:5px;    
}
```

Here is Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/gyQ2W/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use `:before` pseudo-element. As `content` in it you can put images, HTML caracters, etc... Updated your fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/shbfsoq6/2/